# No module named wsgi

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn, foreman

This is what I have in my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath meraki meraki.wsgi
```

and when I do `foreman start`, I get this error:

```
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

the reason, as far as I can see in the traceback, is:

```
ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

I did `import wsgi` in the shell and the import was successful, no errors.

Why can't I start `foreman`?

**Project Structure:**

```
meraki
  meraki
      //other apps
      meraki
          settings
          __init__.py
          celery.py
          views.py
          wsgi.py
      manage.py
  Procfile
  requirements
  requirements.txt
```

Comment: Can you post your project structure?

Comment: Why are you adding the pythonpath parameter?

Comment: Did you fail to list ``__init__.py`` as existing in same directory as the ``wsgi.py`` in your structure above? You would have to have that for it to work at all. It is such a key file that not listing it if it did exist, would cause many wrong conclusions to be made as to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've confused yourself by following an unnecessarily complicated structure. You don't need that outer meraki directory, and your Procfile and requirements.txt should be in the same directory as manage.py. Then you can remove the pythonpath parameter and all should be well.

Comment: You are right. I tried moving them inside and it worked. I am just following the advice given in the book `two scoops of django`. Besides, it is not the first time I am using this structure and it used to work with no problem :) I wonder what happened here :) As a last resort, I will do what you suggested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As Roseman said, it is unnecessarily complicated structure.If you want it to do so,Try

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath /path/to/meraki meraki.wsgi
```

That is `/absolutepath/to/secondmeroki(out of 3)` which contains `apps`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But absolute path is not going to work when I deploy it in production :) So I think as you guys suggested I will simplify the structure and move `Procfile` inside

Comment: Yes, otherwise, you have to setup it differently for your production.